# UINavigation Controller Root View Change

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uistoryboard, navigationcontroller

I recently encountered a small problem with Storyboards. I have a `UINavigationController` than has a relationship with the MainView `RootViewController`(This one has all the buttons leading to the rest of my app). However, I tried to change the `RootViewController` so that I could enable persistent login rather than a UIWebview Login. When I made the new Logon Form `ViewController` as the Root, the buttons on my MainView simply stop working.

I also have set the `UINavigationController` as the initial View Controller.
Any ideas on what has to be done here?

I do know that I can simply have the logon screen in the storyboard and call it programmatically, set it to advance on a boolean condition(loginDidSucceed). However, I am confused on why this behavior happens in StoryBoard.

Solution Referred from: [Present Splash/Login ViewController With StoryBoard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697747/how-to-present-a-splash-login-view-controller-using-storyboards)

Thanks for the Help and Effort!

Comment: The post you are referring to does not suggest changing the root view controller into the login. Instead, it suggests that the login form is shown as a modal ViewController on top of your normal VC hierarchy. Pardon me if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Yeah I know. I just put it there so that people will not suggest that I can do that. I simply referred to solution there to let people who answer this question know that I do know that alternative exists.

Thanks for Checking though @Krumelur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the principal problem here is that the target of your butttons is the old view controller instance; when it goes out of scope their target no longer exists.

Comment: Yes, but even if I delete the push segues and redo the segues. The buttons still do not work.

Comment: imma give u the bounty :P
thanks for the effort of answering!