# How to present a splash/login view controller using storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, appdelegate

I've seen this question in various forms without a clear answer.  I'm going to ask and answer here.  My app needs to do work on startup... inits, a few network calls, login, etc.  I don't want my main view controller working until that's done.  What's a good pattern for doing this?

Requirements:

- iOS5+, storyboards, ARC.
- the main vc's view cannot appear until the startup work is done.
- want a choice of transition styles to the main vc when the startup work is done.
- want to do as much layout as possible in storyboard.
- the code should be cleanly contained somewhere obvious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT, July 2017**
Since the first writing, I've changed my practice to one where I give the start up tasks to their own view controller.  In that VC, I check startup conditions, present a "busy" UI if needed, etc.  Based on the state at startup, I set the window's root VC.

In addition to solving the OP problem, this approach has the additional benefits of giving better control of the startup UI and UI transitions.  Here's how to do it:

In your main storyboard, add a new VC, called `LaunchViewController` and make it the app's initial vc.  Give your app's "real" initial vc an identifier like "AppUI" (identifiers are on the Identity tab in IB).

Identify other vcs that are the starts of main UI flows (e.g. Signup/Login, Tutorial, and so on) and give these descriptive identifiers, too.  (Some prefer to keep each flow in it's own storyboard.  That's a good practice, IMO).

*One other nice optional idea*: give your app's launch storyboard's vc an identifier, too (like "LaunchVC"), so that you can grab it and use it's view during startup.  This will provide a seamless experience for the user during launch and while you do your startup tasks.

Here's what my `LaunchViewController` looks like....

```
@implementation LaunchViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // optional, but I really like this:
    // cover my view with my launch screen's view for a seamless start
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self.class storyboardWithKey:@"UILaunchStoryboardName"];
    UINavigationController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LaunchVC"];
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self hideBusyUI];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self showBusyUI];

    // start your startup logic here:
    // let's say you need to do a network transaction... 
    //
    [someNetworkCallingObject doSomeNetworkCallCompletion:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if (/* some condition */) [self.class presentUI:@"AppUI"];
        else if (/* some condition */) [self.class presentUI:@"LoginUI"];
        // etc.
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Busy UI

// optional, but maybe you want a spinner or something while getting started
- (void)showBusyUI {
    // in one app, I add a spinner on my launch storyboard vc
    // give it a tag, and give the logo image a tag, too
    // here in animation, I fade out the logo and fade in a spinner
    UIImageView *logo = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:32];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *aiv = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[self.view viewWithTag:33];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        logo.alpha = 0.0;
        aiv.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

- (void)hideBusyUI {
    // an animation that reverses the showBusyUI
}

#pragma mark - Present UI

+ (void)presentUI:(NSString *)identifier {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self storyboardWithKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"];
    UINavigationController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;
    window.rootViewController = vc;

    // another bonus of this approach: any VC transition you like to
    // any of the app's main flows
    [UIView transitionWithView:window
                      duration:0.3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:nil
                    completion:nil];
}

+ (UIStoryboard *)storyboardWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *storyboardName = [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:key];
    return [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:bundle];
}

@end
```

**The original answer below, though I prefer my current approach**

Let's express the app's readiness to run the main vc with a boolean, something like:

```
BOOL readyToRun = startupWorkIsDone && userIsLoggedIn;
```

1. Create an AppStartupViewController and lay it out in app storyboard.
2. Don't drag any segue's to it, and don't make it the staring vc, just leave it floating somewhere.
3. In the vc's attributes inspector in storyboard, set it's identifier as "AppStartupViewController".

In the AppStartupViewController.m, when the readyToRun conditions have been met, it can dismiss itself:

```
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;   // your choice here from UIModalTransitionStyle
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now, whenever the app becomes active, it can check for readiness to run, and present the AppStartupViewController if it's needed.
In AppDelegate.h

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    BOOL readyToRun = startupWorkIsDone && userIsLoggedIn;

    if (!readyToRun) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        AppStartupViewController *startupVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AppStartupViewController"];

        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:startupVC animated:NO completion:nil];
        // animate = NO because we don't want to see the mainVC's view
    }
}
```

That's mostly the answer, but there is one hitch.  Unfortunately the main vc gets loaded (that's okay) and gets a viewWillAppear: message (not okay) before the AppStartupViewController is presented.  It means we have to spread a little extra startup logic, like this, in MainViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (readyToRun) {
        // the view will appear stuff i would have done unconditionally before
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, I tried your solution out for my app but I did get the hitch you were mentioning.
Do you mind explaining what the statement "the view will appear stuff I would have done unconditionally before"

Comment: Sure - in the soln I offer, the main vc in your app is going to get two invocations of viewWillAppear: - first before your AppStartup vc is presented, and the second before the main vc is really about to appear.  The problem is that first one.  I'd like my main vc to assume that everything is ready to go before it gets any view messages, but that first (and wrong by Apple, I think) message to viewWillAppear: occurs before I have run my startup logic.  (It's not about to appear, so why should it get that message?) continued...

Comment: As a result, I add the readyToRun condition there.  "the view will appear stuff ..." is anything you plan to do in that method, anything that should only run when the app is ready.  It's tough to express.  Will think about how to edit my soln there for more clarity.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, you're spreading the logic into MainViewController's `viewWillAppear()` however there's no guarantee that this will be the active view controller at the time is there? Or you have to start peppering that check for "readyToRun" all over your app, which is sub-optimal. Wouldn't it be better to encapsulate this logic inside AppDelegate itself?

Comment: @cleverbit - I've changed my approach since writing this article to one that I've described fully in a major edit, and one that shares a key similarity with one of your recent answers -- replace the root window view. (not sure why your answer was down-voted, but I did my part to correct that with a plus one).  My new current practice gives all of this work to a startup vc.  This has several benefits that I describe in the edit.

Comment: @cleverbit - I appreciate your comment because, after I devised my newer approach, I realized that it deprecated this answer, but never dug around SO to find this and fix it.  As to your point about needing to make "readyToRun" calls everywhere, I haven't found this to be the case, maybe because of the app states where the check's I do have been needed (e.g. on launch vs. becoming active).

Comment: Thanks @danh glad I could help. I've asked (and answered) a similar question here, which might provide further insight for people looking for more information on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321570/swift-changing-the-rootviewcontroller-in-appdelegate-to-present-main-or-login-o

Answer (score 0):

Another solution when using a navigation controller.

1. Your navigation controller being the initial view controller, set your main controller as the navigation controller root's view.
2. Add your loading controller to the storyboard and link with a named segue of style modal.
3. In your main controller's viewWillAppear trigger the segue (only once per app run).

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(_isFirstRun)
    {
        _isFirstRun = NO;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueLoading" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

It will not work if you trigger the segue in viewDidLoad probably because the navigation controller's animation is not done yet and you will receive an `unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions`