# How to manage startup problems at the GUI level?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interface, exit

I'm working in an application that loads a few remote jsons at startup.  The application has been programmed to do certain tests on the incoming data to prevent invalid states and to detect possible human errors.  However, I am not sure of how we should treat such situation at the GUI level - our initial idea was to display a "Oops there was an unexpected server error.  We are working to solve this issue.  Please, try again later." popup to quit the application when the user hits an "Ok" or "Exit" button.

Apple apparently discourages exiting the application from within your code: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1561.html

What good alternatives are there to handle this situation?

**Update:** I updated the error message above, since it was misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue. My app was useless unless it could establish a connection to a server.

There are two ways around this:

1. place holder text, this can hold the position until you can get your json arrays, or at least allow a back drop for popping an alert.
2. Load a view with all interaction disabled, with a small message box saying "connecting..."

Basically I have taken the first responding storyboard frame and disabled everything that the user could touch. I just allowed static interaction like pressing a button to get to the about screen.

Don't beat yourself up too much about it though. If you don't have any connectivity at all then none of the user's apps are going to be functioning properly. I think in this state, from a GUI perspective it is mostly about damage control and protecting the user experience.

Comment: I should clarify... the error message I wrote above was a bit off.  The kind of failure I'm guarding against is errors in the App's startup info - which is downloaded and checked to some extent.  I wanted to display a generic message suggesting the player to try again later.  This would give the app's owner some time to fix eventual human mistakes.

Comment: Oh ok - well I think some of what I said can be salvaged. I think the best option is to keep your pop-up box. But instead of OK-EXIT as option, have Retry and Exit - that way the user can at least sit there hitting retry (at which point you should throw up a spinner box) Or exit and try again later. Remember this is designing for the worst-case-scenario

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to be graceful at startup.  I suggest presenting UI modally while your app gets ready to run.  I asked and answered [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697747/how-to-present-a-splash-login-view-controller-using-storyboards) which shows a clean way to do the UI, including nice transition effects.

As for exiting:  Your app should never self-terminate (copyright Arnold Schwartzenegger circa 2003).  The correct app behavior when it can't get something done that has to be done modally is to alert the user and give the option to retry.  If the user wants to not retry, there's a hardware home button on the phone.