# how to add an initial view in Xcode4 for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, uiviewcontroller

My game app presently has a single ViewController and XIB for playing game.
I added a new ViewController and XIB for the initial (bootup) view.

How do I get the app to boot into this initial view?   I can't figure it out.

FYI, the initial screen is for nice, welcome graphcs and a couple of setup controls.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697747/how-to-present-a-splash-login-view-controller-using-storyboards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your appDelegate's function

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 //DesiredStartUpViewController is the class which u wanna call at start up
 DesiredStartUpViewController * yourDesiredViewController = [[DesiredStartUpViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourDesiredViewController"];

 UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:yourDesiredViewController];

 [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project settings choose target. Then click "Summary" and you have to set splash screen below.It will show as the loading screen.