# can not do modal on modal view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

**Goal** : show a splash screen in certain of time (3 seconds ) then log-in view appears for authentication process  and if this authentication is successful, go to main page ( this effect is used by many applications  such as facebook )

What I am doing is

**1.set the root of navigation to be `MainViewController`**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.isLogIn = FALSE;
  self.window  =   [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  MainViewController    *mainView      =   [[MainViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
  self.navigationController            =   [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainView];
  self.window.rootViewController       =   navigationController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
```

}

**2.Present `LogInViewController` as modalViewController in `MainViewController`**

```
@implementation MainViewController
-(void) viewDidLoad {
  appDelegate                        =   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  LogInController   *logInController =   [[LogInController alloc]                 initWithNibName:@"LogInController"      bundle:nil];

  if ( !appDelegate.isLogIn )
     [self presentModalViewController:logInController animated:NO]; 
}
```

**3.Present `splashScreen` as modalViewController in `LogInViewController`**

```
#implementation LogInViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title                     =   @"Sign in";
    SplashScreen *splashController =   [[SplashScreen alloc]           initWithNibName:@"SplashScreen"         bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:splashController animated:NO];
    ;
}
```

}

**4.In splashScreen, dismiss itself after certain of time**

```
@implementation SplashScreen
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeSplashScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:6.0];                         

}

-(void)removeSplashScreen{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Problem** : 
the log in view is shown but a splashScreen is not presented before log in view.

I found out that the method of `viewDidLoad` of `SplashScreen` is not invoked at all.

Can somebody explain it to me and point out what I am missing here.
All comments are welcomed here.

Comment: does SplashScreen appears on screen?

Comment: no splashScreen does not appear at all

Comment: I wrestled with this sort of problem, too.  So much so that I decided to post my answer on SO.  Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697747/how-to-present-a-splash-login-view-controller-using-storyboards

Comment: thanks for your post but before moving on, I need to know what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Do this as problem is with your appDelegate's reference

```
@implementation MainViewController
-(void) viewDidLoad {
   appDelegate                        =   (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   LogInController   *logInController =   [[LogInController alloc]                 initWithNibName:@"LogInController"      bundle:nil];

   if ( !appDelegate.isLogIn )
   [self presentModalViewController:logInController animated:NO]; 
 }
```