# Storyboard with two separate flows

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

My app asks the user to sign up the first time he uses it. The sign up flow has three screens that the user needs to complete.

After the user has completed the signup flow, he enters the app's main UI.

What is the best way to handle that flow change with storyboards?

My best guess is to use two storyboards, a main storyboard and a signup storyboard, then at runtime, check if the sign up flow is needed and load the signup storyboard,
otherwise load the main storyboard.

Is that the best or most common way to deal with two flows, and if so, how do I switch to the main storyboard after the sign up flow is finished?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697747/how-to-present-a-splash-login-view-controller-using-storyboards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have everything in one storyboard, and it will work just fine. You can just choose which view controller you want to instantiate during app launch.

First you need to go to the settings for your target and remove the storyboard from where it says "Main Interface". Then you'll want to have code like the following in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in your app delegate:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController = nil;

BOOL needsSignUp = //Your check for whether you need to sign in or not here

if (needsSignUp) {
    viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignUpScreen"];
}
else {
    viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainAppScreen"];
}

self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This is just deciding which view controller to instantiate manually from the storyboard after you manually instantiate the storyboard. You'll want to replace `@"SignUpScreen"` and `@"MainAppScreen"` with the actual identifiers of your view controllers in your storyboard.

Make sure you follow the first step, removing the storyboard from the "Main Interface" in your target, because that's what makes it automatically instantiate your storyboard and choose the initial view controller automatically, which you no longer want it to do.

EDIT:

Every view controller has a reference to the storyboard that it was instantiated from, so when you finish sign up and want to display your main app screen, you just need to call the following line to get it:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainAppScreen"];
```

If you're using a `UINavigationController` to display your sign up screens, you can replace the view controller stack by doing this:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[viewController] animated:YES];
```

If you wanted to set your main screen view controller as the root view controller, or set any other view as the root view controller, you could do this:

```
self.view.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

Comment: What about when the user finishes sign-up.  Presumably the OP wants the main UI at that time.  Will user have to terminate the app and relaunch to get the main UI?

Comment: No, you just have it go to the main UI at that time by displaying that view controller from the storyboard. If you're using a UINavigationController, you could replace the view controller stack on that with your new one, or you could set a new root view controller on the window.

Comment: That sounds good.  I think a little instruction along those lines would improve your answer.

Comment: @danh I added some more to it.