# TabbarView Controller move View with tabbar item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

As I am new to ios and working on tabbarview Controller. Everything fine but when i try to move view of tabbar then item is move but view is not move i.e 
`self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=1;` then tabbaritem move at index 1 but view is still on index 0. Help me out.May be there is some silly mistake there :).

Comment: if you are using storyboard plz take a screen shot of it

Comment: show your storyboard!!!! Check if you have different view controllers with different colors, connected to your tab bar and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: As i have less reputation so i am not able to upload Image.

Comment: please refere this link may be it help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606715/ios-how-open-tab-bar-controller-from-viewcontroller-using-storyboards)

Comment: i did the same @Riddhi.. But i don't know why the view controller move.