# How do I present a UITabBarController at a specific index?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Right now I have my user finish onboarding from a `UIPageViewController` and tap a "FINISHED" button to go to the profile tab of my `UITabBarController`. However, the profile tab is at index [2], and the code below is taking me to index [0].

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabHostController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How do I present the `UITabBarController` at a specific index [2] after tapping the "FINISHED" button from the `UIPageViewController`?

Answers in objective-c, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can change `selectedIndex` property of the **TabBarController** to make it open the index you want

```
UITabBarController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabHostController"];
vc.selectedIndex = 2; // or [vc setSelectedIndex:2];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This is a combination of Swift and Objective C code. OP has asked for Objective C code. Plus the syntax seems incorrect.

Comment: I don't recall keyword " as! UITabBarController" in Objective C. And there is semi-colon after each line

Comment: Still incorrect. You haven't cast vc to TabBarController class. TabBarController is a custom UITabBarController.

Comment: see here same way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606715/ios-how-open-tab-bar-controller-from-viewcontroller-using-storyboards?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: To add : There are other minor syntax errors as well. Like in UITabBarController*vc, there should be a space before * and second code line should end with semi-colon

Comment: hahahaa this is not the big deal anyone knows objective-c has semicolons and swift hasn't , besides it may because of i work with both the languages , but the problem poster will for sure skip that minor mistakes

Comment: It is a big deal. Since here it is expected to provide a working solution. You are having a good reputation on StackOverFlow and it is expected from an experienced user to provide syntactically correct answer.

Comment: regarding spacing this UITabBarController*vc and this UITabBarController *vc will work , semicolon is commented when i edited for an alternate code snippet

Comment: Since you have now removed all syntax errors, I am revoking my downvote and uprooting your answer. But please remember, answers on StackOverflow are reflected in the code. For a beginner who will be looking for an answer, this will be the code he'll refer to. So it should be thoroughly correct. Having said that, I am editing few things to make the above code clean.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following in one of my app where I had to display 3rd tab. Nothing more than one line of code in `viewDidLoad` of **TabBarController** :

```
[self setSelectedIndex:2];
```

And if you have to present 3rd tab only at the start i.e. after Onboarding and for rest of the launches you have to present 1st tab then in the `viewDidLoad` of 3rd tab's UIViewController, assign a boolean `NSUserDefault` :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"loadThirdTab"];
```

So now your `viewDidLoad` for **TabBarController** will be :

```
if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"loadThirdTab"]] != nil &&[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"loadThirdTab"])
   [self setSelectedIndex:0];
else
    [self setSelectedIndex:2];
```

Comment: he can set  selectedIndex before opening no need to complicate code with userdefaults

Comment: I don't see any complication with that. Either of the solution will work.